# Springdoc ignoring "is" prefix for attributes like "isSelected"

Tags: java, springdoc

using default springdoc configuration to generate swagger for my spring boot application.
We use "is" prefix pro boolean attributes in our api request and response but in generated api documentation there is not the "is" prefix.

Example:

```
public class Foo{

private boolean isSelected;
private boolean isValid; 
}
```

Swagger:

```
   Foo:
      type: object
         properties:
           selected:
             type: boolean
           valid:
             type: boolean
```

Is there any configuration to not ignore "is" prefix for springdoc?

Thank you for any response

Comment: What is interesting, when you replace `boolean` by `Boolean` the "is" part is not ignored. Moreover `boolean` property is not marked by Springdoc as required no matter if you give `@Schema(required = true)` or `@NotNull`. But for `Boolean` it is handled correctly. Sounds like a bug in Springdoc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really depends on your `Jackson Mapper` settings.
But you can force it to use it, by using below mentioned methods:

1. Using `@JsonProperty` Annotation method:

```java
public class Foo {

    @JsonProperty("selected")
    private boolean isSelected;

    @JsonProperty("valid")
    private boolean isValid;

}
```

2. Using `getter` method:

```java
public class Foo {

    private boolean isSelected;
    private boolean isValid;

    public boolean isSelected() {

        return isSelected;
    }

    public boolean isValid() {
        return isValid;
    }

}
```

Comment: Together with Lombok, getter methods were the problem. Thank you